# laravel 5.2 Bootstrap TouchSpin get value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

```
{!! Form::open(['url' =>'users/store/'.$user->id, 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}
<input id="score" name="score" type="text" value="0>
{!! Form::submit('In',  ['name' => 'in', 'class' => 'btn btn-md btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}


<script>
    $("input[name='score']").TouchSpin({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 0.1,
        decimals: 2,
        boostat: 5,
        maxboostedstep: 10,
        postfix: '%'
    });
</script>
```

And my Controller is

```
return Input::get('score');
```

Controller return nothing .. i can't get value from (name="score")
if i remove Touch-spins everything works find ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is ..

```
<input type="text" id="score" name="score" class="form-control">
```

And

```
<script>
$( "#score" ).change(function() {
var i = $( "#score" ).val();
var ii = ""+i+".00";
$( "#score" ).val(ii);
 });
</script>
```